# GWT default style name

Tags: html, gwt

I'm using GWT for create a web-application; by default Google Web Toolkit append your style name.

For example the following code

```
Anchor myAnchor = new Anchor("Test");
```

create this HTML

```
< a href=".." class="**gwt-Anchor**">Test< /a>
```

Can i remove ALL gwt style name on ALL widget?

In example I want remove gwt-Anchor class, but I don't want run removeStyleName("gwt-Anchor")

Thanks

Comment: And what is the problem if it is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setStylePrimaryName()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setStylePrimaryName%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
Anchor myAnchor = new Anchor("Test");
myAnchor.setStylePrimaryName("mystyle");
```

**As per docs** :

```
Sets the object's primary style name and updates all dependent style names.
```

Comment: It's best, but it's need to create a custom class. Thanks All!

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do it, no. You have to explicitly `removeStyleName(…)` or more simply `setStyleName("")` on each widget.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove the style then apply new style using setStyleName(""). So In your project style sheet file, Define gwt-Anchor style with empty brace which tag already exist in GWT style.

Thus you can inherit same style name with `!important` keyword in gwt project. it will apply project css. and it will **remove all GWT style.** so copy style name and paste in your project css. i.e.

**style.css**

```
.gwt-Anchor
{
 //Any style you want to apply 
}
```